# Load Postgres dump after docker-compose up

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a dump.sql file that I would like to load with docker-compose.

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  postgres:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: my_db_name
      POSTGRES_USER: my_name
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./devops/db/Dockerfile.db
```

My Dockerfile.db is really simple at the moment:

```
FROM postgres
MAINTAINER me <me@me.me>

COPY ./devops/db ./devops/db
WORKDIR ./devops/db
```

I would like to run a command like `psql my_db_name < dump.sql` at some point. If I run a script like this from the Dockerfile.db, the issue is that the script is run after build but before `docker-compose up`, and the database is not running yet.

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Generally, I've done this by writing a bash script that does a docker-compose up -d, then a docker-compose exec db_service_name with the command to execute the SQL dump.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Reading https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/, the section 'Extend this image' explains that any .sql in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d will be executed after build.

I just needed to change my Dockerfile.db to:

```
FROM postgres

ADD ./devops/db/dummy_dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

And it works!

Comment: The documentation indicates can that `*.sh` scripts can also be used, which provides much wider flexibility. I've used this to `pg_restore` a `.dump` file.

Comment: I am trying this approach and I'm getting the following:


postgres    | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump-202105231637-1.sql
postgres    | The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump.
postgres    | Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database.

any ideas ?

Comment: I also got "The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump.
 Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database." so not working for me

Answer (score 26):

Another option that doesn't require a Dockerfile would be to mount your sql file into the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder using the `volumes` attribute of `docker-compose`.
The official postgres image https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ will import and execute all SQL files placed in that folder. So something like

```
services:
  postgres:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: my_db_name
      POSTGRES_USER: my_name
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
  volumes:
    - ./devops/db/dummy_dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dummy_dump.sql
```

This will automatically populate the specified `POSTGRES_DB` for you.

Comment: The problem that I'm experiencing with this solution is that if the 'dump.sql' does't exist on the host machine, Docker will create an empty 'dump.sql' FOLDER inside the container for some reason.. causing the postgres container to fail.

Comment: Life saver +1 love ya

Answer (score 18):

```
sudo docker exec postgres psql -U postgres my_db_name < dump.sql
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: it solves importing dump without tweaking dockerfile like in accepted answer.. also what do i need to explain in this piece: `psql -U postgres my_db_name < dump.sql` ? if you having troubles in this level, may be it's better to read the basics

Comment: This worked for me, but needs `-i` after `exec` so it is `sudo docker exec -i postgres psql -U postgres my_db_name < dump.sql`

Comment: Also, exec requires (I believe?) that the Docker system is already booted, which may not be compatible with importing a full database dump.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pg_restore` inside the container:

```bash
cat ${BACKUP_SQL_File} | docker exec -i ${CONTAINER_NAME} pg_restore \
    --verbose \
    --clean \
    --no-acl \
    --no-owner \
    -U ${USER} \
    -d ${DATABASE}
```

Answer (score 4):

After the `docker-compose up`, do `docker ps` it will give you a list of active docker containers. From that, you can get the container ID.

Then,

```bash
docker exec -i ${CONTAINER_ID} psql -U ${USER} < ${SQL_FILE}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to restore from I dump I use an sh to restore the database.

If you use a dump with docker-entrypoint-initdb.d it gives the error "The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump. Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database."

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    container_name: postgis_my_db_name
    image: postgis/postgis:14-3.3
    ports:
      - "5430:5432"
    # restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./my_db_name.sql:/my_db_name.sql
    - ./restore.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/restore.sh
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
      POSTGRES_DB: my_db_name
```

restore.sh

```
 pg_restore -d my_db_name my_db_name.sql
```

Comment: I am getting pg_restore: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "<my_database>" does not exist
custompostgres exited with code 1
dependency failed to start: container for service "dataspace_postgres" exited (1)

Answer (score 1):

```bash
CONTAINER_NAME="postgres"
DB_USER=postgres
LOCAL_DUMP_PATH="..."
docker run --name "${CONTAINER_NAME}" postgres
docker exec -i "${CONTAINER_NAME}" psql -U "${DB_USER}" < "${LOCAL_DUMP_PATH}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it  without a dockerfile :

```
# start first container
docker compose start $db_container

# dump intial database
docker compose exec db pg_dump -U $user -Fc $database > $dump_file

# start container db
docker compose start $db_container

# get container id 
docker ps

# copy to container
docker cp $dump_file $container_id:/var

# delete database container / Can't use
docker compose exec $db_container dropdb -U $user $database

# user pg_restore
docker compose exec $db_container pg_restore -U $user -C -d postgres /var/$dump_file
```