# How to execute scripts after docker-compose up?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make my dev process easier/maintainable using docker(-compose).
I do not want to use any volumes (if that's possible).
Why does import.sh not get executed after I run 'docker-compose up -d'?

I have the following files:

```
docker-compose.yml
  mysql
  ---- import.sh
  ---- db.sql
  ---- Dockerfile
```

in **docker-compose.yml** there is:

```
version: '2'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql
    build:
      context: ./mysql/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: mysqltest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
```

in **/mysql/Dockerfile** there is:

```
ADD import.sh /tmp/import.sh
ADD db.sql /tmp/db.sql
RUN /tmp/import.sh
```

in **/mysql/db.sql** there is:

```
CREATE DATABASE test1;
CREATE DATABASE test2;
CREATE DATABASE test3;
```

Comment: The Dockerfile gets run when the image is _built_. Docker Compose will build your image for you before running it. So your script should be running _before_ you run `docker-compose up -d`, not _after_.

Comment: It sounds like you just want your database dump to run _after_ the mysql daemon starts. In that case, use `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, Documented on the [MySQL Dockerhub Page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) and also explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781984/load-postgres-dump-after-docker-compose-up/36782751#36782751 (functions the same for Postgres and MySQL).

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to achieve, and it worked for me, thank you. But what if I want to run other scripts after the build-process / when all containers are ready?

Comment: The answer below from fzgregor explains the best way to do that.

Comment: Just a small addition on what @mkasberg had cleverly suggested, the scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` solution will by executed only on a fresh start of a container (ie, if you are using a named volume to persist data that already contain database files, the scripts will be ignored). You may find a good post about this [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/203#issuecomment-255200501)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` in your Dockerfile to execute a command when the container starts. The difference between them is that `ENTRYPOINT` is executed any time the container is started, while `CMD` might be replaced with an command line option. Assuming the command you want to execute is `X`

```
docker run my-image Y
```

will execute `X` if `ENTRYPOINT X` was in the Dockerfile and `Y` if `CMD X` was in the Dockerfile.

However, there are two caveats:

1. The command will be executed every time the container is started.
2. After the command terminates the container is shut down.

Therefore, a typical solution is to have a `docker-entrypoint` script. It checks whether it is run in a fresh container initiating its environment and afterwards executes the container's actual program.
Have a look at the [official mysql Dockerfile and entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/eeb0c33dfcad3db46a0dfb24c352d2a1601c7667/8.0) to get an idea.

An example entrypoint script could look like this:

```
$ cat docker_entrypoint.sh                                                                                                                                          
if [ ! -f .initialized ]; then                                                                                                                                                                                    
    echo "Initializing container"                                                                                                                                                                                 
    # run initializing commands                                                                                                                                                                                   
    touch .initialized                                                                                                                                                                                            
fi                                                                                                                                                                                                                

exec "$@"
```

First, it checks whether there is a file called `.initialized`. If there is none, some commands are run to initialize the container environment. After which `touch .initialized` creates `.initialized` as an empty file. Therefore, subsequent container starts won't execute the initialization command again.
Secondly, it starts the actual service. Doing this with `exec` will replace the shell process with the service's process. Hence, docker will keep the container running until the service terminates. `"$@"` will contain the "container/image command". This is set with `CMD X` in the Dockerfile and is overriden on the command, as I already pointed out above. By using `exec "$@"` you will be able to start different programs in the container for inspection, e.g. `bash`, and start the service by default, as specified in the Dockerfile's `CMD` statement.

Comment: Can someone edit this ? Are `X` and `Y` scripts ? Of the two caveats what applies to `CMD` vs `ENTRYPOINT` ?

Comment: As I understand it, `Y` is a reference to a docker image whereas the `X` is a reference to a command such as `apachectl`

Comment: No, `X` and `Y` are two different commands

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to initialize your db in the very first time, you can use this easy way.

```
    volumes:
      - [the scripts dir]:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

> Initializing a fresh instance
>   When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

Doc is here: https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/